# OpenShift Cronjob schedule to run on only on 1st Wednesday of a month

Tags: openshift

I'm converting my cronjob schedule from Unix to OpenShift (by creating yaml file) and i'm not finding the option to schedule it to run on a certain day in yaml file. I tried these options, but it still doesn't work.

00 5 0-7 * * [ `date +\%u` = 3 ] && > (this is what i've in Unix)

schedule: '00 05 * * 3/1' (this runs even on second Wednesday)

schedule: '00 05 0-7 * 3'

schedule: '00 05 0-7 * "[ `date +\%u` = 3 ]"' - Throws error while creation (Invalid value: "00 05 * * "[ `date +\\%u` = 3 ]"": Expected exactly 5 fields)

schedule: '00 05 * * 3#1' - Throws error while creation ("00 05 * * 3#1": Failed to parse int from 3#1: strconv.Atoi: parsing "3#1")

Comment: To attract more attention, please improve your code formatting.

Comment: Sounds like you want your schedule to be `0 5 * * *`, then have your `date` based check being executed in your command. The schedule part expects integers, as stated by your error message.